# NLB health check is failing when using ALB as the target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, nlb

I am using the Network load balancer (NLB) which is using the Application load balancer (ALB) as the target group

And when the health check performs for the ALB for its target group it is getting passed and instance is healthy.

Application load balancer(ALB) on HTTPS:443 listener

[image]

ALB target group health check passing
[image]

But when the NLB health check is performed it is getting failed

[image]

Health Check tab NLB---ALB target group

[image]

Can anybody suggest anything

Comment: can you confirm the health check path configured on the NLB to check the ALB is correct ?

Comment: Health check path on NLB is /HealthCheck.ashx, and the protocol used is https with port 443. Https and 443 is used just because the ALB is accepting the traffic on protocol https  and port is 443. But still health is failing

Answer (score 0):

try TCP protocal in your healtcheck , NLB supports the TCP for 443

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well for days I could not figure it out but the Security group of the ALB needs to allow traffic from the NLB.